# How can electrical conductivity of pure water be increased?

Tags: electrons, water, conductors

I know that impure water(containing salts) or acidified water can conduct electricity but pure water is a poor conductor of electricity. So is it possible? Please explain.

Comment: To make pure water more conductive, you could add salt or other impurities. What kind of answer did you have in mind?

Comment: Photon.......I wanted a answer like Floris gave. I wanted to know of any possibilities to make pure water better conductor, keeping its purity i.e. by NOT adding impurities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conductivity in water is due to the presence of ions.

Pure water has few ions at room temperature: the dissociation constant is about $10^{-14}$ at room temperature, increasing almost 50x as you reach the boiling point [reference](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/kw.html). Higher dissociation = better conductivity.

So it's possible to increase the conductivity of pure water significantly by heating it.

I found a graph of this relationship in the [Suez water treatment handbook](https://www.suezwaterhandbook.com/formulas-and-tools/formulary/chemistry-and-reagents/characteristics-solution-constants) that shows roughly a 20x increase in conductivity between 20°C and 100°C . Now the since the dissociation constant is the product of $\rm[OH^-]$ and $\rm[H_3O^+]$ concentrations, while the conductivity depends on the total number of ions and their mobility, you would expect conductivity to scale roughly with the square root of the dissociation constant; but there will be an added factor due to ion mobility (which will increase with temperature). So ~20x increase in conductivity is a reasonable value.

[image]

Comment: Conductivity in solutions also depends on [electrical mobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_mobility);  it's not clear to me how this would vary with temperature, though I wouldn't be surprised if it increases as well.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - good point. See update.